# remove plus symbol from email regex php

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I want to remove + symbol from email please help me to write a regex that doesn't accept + symbol in email.

```
abc@xyz.com - valid email
abc123@xyz.com - valid email
abc.def@xyz.com - valid email
abc+123@xyz.com - Invalid email
```

Comment: [**`^[^@+]+@\S+$`**](https://regex101.com/r/z7stuw/1) will probably do - the question remains: why? `+` is totally valid.

Comment: i am using regex for email validation that doesn't accept email with + sign and through error
str_replcae is nit useful here

Comment: @Jan getting error  Unknown modifier '@'

Comment: @codex use a different delimiter for your pattern. Wrap it in `/`

Comment: E.g. `~` as delimiter. @ctwheels

Comment: Thanks @ctwheels  this works for me

Comment: Thanks @Jan this works for me

Answer (score 5):

As per my comment, you could probably use

```
^[^@+]+@\S+$
# start of line, anything not + or @ 1+ times, followed by @,
# not whitespaces and the end of the string
```

Use e.g. `~` as delimiter and see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/z7stuw/1) - question is: why? `+` is totally valid.

Answer (score 2):

Plus symbol is a valid email character.

You tagged this `php`.  You shouldn't be using regexes for email validation in PHP.  You should be using `filter_var()`

Example:

```
filter_var('bob@example.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
```

Answer (score 2):

**Regex**: [`^[^@+]+@[^@]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/xqnUa1/1)

Add unwanted chars in `[^@+]`.

Details:

- `^` Asserts position at start of a line
- `[^]` Match a single character not present in the list
- `+` Matches between one and unlimited times
- `$` Asserts position at the end of a line

**PHP code**:

```
$strings=['abc@xyz.com','abc123@xyz.com','abc.def@xyz.com','abc+123@xyz.com'];

foreach($strings as $string){
    $match = preg_match('~^[^@+]+@[^@]+$~', $string);
    echo ($string . ' ' . ($match ? 'true' : 'false')."\n");
}
```

Output:

```
abc@xyz.com true
abc123@xyz.com true
abc.def@xyz.com true
abc+123@xyz.com false
```